# set up Apache2 virtual hosts and now MongoDB connection refused

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, apache2

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on an AWS EC2 instance with Apache2. This morning I upgraded my Apache2 settings to allow multiple virtual servers following these instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Just now I tried to access my MongoDB instance, but I cannot do it either through the PHP MongoDB driver or through the shell. I get this error when attempting to connect with a PHP MongoClient():

```
Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Connection refused'
```

and I get this error when trying to run the mongo shell:

```
2015-06-03T19:23:57.307+0000 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-06-03T19:23:57.308+0000 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

Everything was running fine just last night, and I haven't directly modified MongoDB settings. What can I do to fix this? How do Apache2 settings relate to MongoDB? I've been trying to look through the MongoDB docs, but I don't see anything that looks relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I went through the logs, I saw a message that there was insufficient room for "journal file." I rebooted my AMI on an EC2 instance with more storage and reinstalled Mongo. That did the trick. I had uploaded a few files to the instance after updating my Apache2 settings, so those few more files must have pushed the instance past what Mongo could tolerate. Too bad the error message wasn't more helpful, but I should have checked the logs sooner. It would also be nice if the logs had a more explicit message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup Security Group for your EC2 instance. And allow Inbound connection for the mongodb port, in your case `27017`.

Comment: I was accessing it from within the same instance. Also it had already been working.